# jsoup doesn't fetch the whole pre-tag content

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup to fetch word information from www2.lingsoft.fi/cgi-bin/fintwol. 
I am using the followong code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www2.lingsoft.fi/cgi-bin/fintwol?word=" + wordForm).get();
Element result = doc.getElementsByTag("pre").first();
System.out.println(result.text());
```

There is only one pre tag on the page. I get all the content if the word form I provide has only one basic form, but I can't achieve the same if there are more lines. 
For example, it works with word "olla", but doesn't with "sietää". It the latter case I get just the first line of the pre contents.

Why could it be like this? And what can I do?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get for both words only one `pre` element.

Comment: What do you expect in the second case?